# Print an image using jsPDF coming from mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, canvas, jspdf

```
//CASE 1
let imageFromInternet = `someURL.jpg`
doc.addImage(imageFromInternet , "JPEG", 30, 20, 50, 50);


//CASE 2
let image = `${baseURL}/${logo}`; //image from mongodb
doc.addImage(image, "JPEG", 30, 80, 50, 50);
```

In **CASE 1**, it gets printed

In **CASE 2**, I get the following error.
*addImage does not support files of type 'UNKNOWN', please ensure that a plugin for 'UNKNOWN' support is added.*

**Note**
I am using reactjs 17.0.1 and jsPDF 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF cannot print directly image from url.

If you allow me one shameless plug: [generate-pdf-from-react-html](https://github.com/Milen-Minchev/generate-pdf-from-react-html)

You can add image directly from mongodb into `img` tag and print the html element.

Comment: But it does print an image in CASE 1

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi can you share the code and the output please?